# jQuery $.ajax success not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I looked at the Network tab in chrome and it's sending the right data (action, username, password) but it's not returning the message into $('#return_login').  What is wrong with my code?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $('.login').hide();

    $('#login').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.login').fadeIn(500);

        $('#login_submit').click(function() {

            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: './controller',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'action=login&username=' + username + "&password=" + password,
                success: function(return_login) {
                    $('#return_login').html(return_login);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

PHP (Methods class isn't used at all, ignore it):

```
<?php
    require_once('Methods.php');

    $Methods = new Methods;

        $action = @$_POST['action'];

        switch($action) {
            case 'login':
                echo 'lol';
            break;
        }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to change `#return_login` to `#login_result`?

Comment: Why would I need to do that..?

Comment: In your question you said `not returning the message into $('#login_result')`, but `#login_result` is not in that block of code

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry I didn't mean to put that in the post.  Editing now.

Comment: are you sure the selector `$('#return_login')` is the right one and it exists... can you do a `console.log(return_login)` in the success handler... also make sure the success handler is getting called

Comment: Also there is a another issue with the code... ie registering an event handler within another one?

Comment: Can you confirm you're receiving a response from the server? Open the request in the Dev Tools Network tab and view the **Response** tab.

Comment: @MattStone I'm getting two.  The first says Request URL:http://localhost/curious/controller
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently the second says Request URL:http://localhost/curious/controller/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: you are setting the `type` as `post` and sending the data via `get` method..either change the type to `get` or change the format

Comment: Check var_dump($_REQUEST) in php if u get the parameters

Comment: Make sure a html container with id `return_login` exists in your page

Comment: @ubercooluk I did that, didn't solve much.  Changed $action = @$_GET['action'] to @$_POST['action'];

Comment: did you change the format in your ajax call ?

Comment: The type was already POST, I also changed the data to JSON.

Comment: @RossUlbricht is any data ('lol') returned in the successful request (200)? 

If not, try setting the request URL to `/controller/index.php` directly.

Do you have any URL rewriting in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/controller',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{action:'login',username:username,password:password},
                success: function(return_login) {
                    $('#return_login').html(return_login);
                }
            });
```

//php

```
 $action = @$_POST['action'];
```

And in the php make sure to put an exit after the switch statment

Comment: I did both to no avail.

Comment: change the url to your php_file_name.php instead of controller

Answer (score 0):

Try sending data in json format:

```
data:{action:'login',username:username,password:password}
```

Comment: This won't change anything - jQuery converts the `data` object into a query string behind the scenes.